# MongoDB Realm Trigger when a field in full document has a specific value

Tags: mongodb, triggers, realm

I am using Express/NodeJs and Mongoose as the backend for a Flutter app. I have multiple collections in MongoDB. For my USERS collection, ***USING REALM UI***, I want to trigger a function when a document is inserted or updated, but only if the "status" field of the inserted/updated document is not equal to an empty string.

Reading the [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/triggers/database-triggers#database-trigger-configuration), I believe with the $match expression, I can look to see if the value of "status" is **CHANGED** to an empty string using the expression below:

```
{
  "updateDescription.updatedFields": {
    "status": ""
  }
}
```

But that is not what I want. I want to fire the trigger only if the value for "status" field **AFTER** update or insert is an empty string. It could have been an empty string before update as well.

The solution so far for me is to let the trigger get fired, but then in the function I check for the value of the "status" field to do what I need to do, but that means the trigger will be fired too many unnecessary times since the "status" field has an empty string 80% of the time.

Answer (score 0):

Notifications are Realm, Collection or Object based so it's not possible to only observe a specific property on all objects* with a Realm Notification.

One possible solution is to address this from an emitter perspective. In other words if you don't care about objects that have their property set to "", then don't post a notification when that happens.

This solution concept applies to all coding platforms but since that was not specified in the question, here's a Swift solution - it should be pretty easy to follow

In this example we're observing all of the people in our database and want to be notified of when a person's `status` property is not "".

To start we get a results object `peopleResults` and add an observer (code omitted for brevity) managed with `peopleToken`

Then we are changing jay's status to "away". This will call the code in the else statement to write those changes, which will then fire a notification event.

On the other hand, if updatedStatus is set to "", then the code in the first section of the if statement is called, writing that change *without firing a notification*.

```
let peopleResults = realm.objects(PersonClass.self)
let peopleToken = peopleResults.observe.... //add an observer to the peopleResults

//change jays status to away
let jay = self.peopleResults.filter("name == 'Jay'").first!

let updatedStatus = "away"
if updatedStatus == "" {
    try! realm.write(withoutNotifying: [peopleToken], {
        jay.status = updatedStatus
    })
} else {
    try! realm.write {
        jay.status = updatedStatus
    }
}
```

*Keeping in mind that Realm objects are KVO compliant so an observer could be added to each specific object's property to watch for changes on those objects

Comment: Thanks for the response. However, maybe I should have been more clear in my question about achieving my goal using Realm UI on MongoDB website. I have updated my question to reflect that.